# how to pass the values from one html page to another html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to pass the values from one html page to another html page but i am getting some errors..

below is my html page one code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function first() {
            location.href = "onclick2.html";
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="first()" >Home</button>
    <form action="onclick2.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="sender" />
    <input type="submit" value="send"/> 

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

below is my html page 2 code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function first() {
            location.href = "onclick.html";
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="first()">Home2</button>
        <form action="onclick.html" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="reciver" />

    </body>
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: I totally don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: values are not passing from one page to another page....

Comment: The only way to pass form content like that is to use `method="get"` in the form, then in your 2nd page's JS code, read the parameters by parsing `document.location` i.e. splitting it at `?` then again at `&`.

Comment: Another way is to store the fields in local storage, then read that on the 2nd page. The reason why you have to use these workarounds is that usually, form content is processed by server-side scripting, not JavaScript.

Comment: apply the url extension `http://example.com?yourdata=data`

Comment: see the answer posted here will do the task http://stackoverflow.com/a/40183315/7040620

Answer (score 0):

you can pass value in url and transfer it as given below :

```
location.href = "http://www.domainname.com/login.html?FirstName=admin&LastName=admin"
```